# What can I do from not booting Freebsd box command line

Tags: boot, freebsd, pfsense

I got a message

```
Can't load 'kernel'
```

And computer is not booting. I have simple commands like `ls` and `lsdev`, but I don't have `cd` or `cat`. How can I find kernel and check if it is ok with these commands?

`ls` shows 2 column list of apparent directories and files, but I can't `ls` with path

---

Although `ls` shows some (d)irectories, like `bin` or `dev`, entering

```
OK ls bin
open 'bin' failed, no such file or directory
```

---

Computer was booting ok and stop do this after power outage. Also it can do automatic update which I didn't notice.

---

```
OK lsdev
     disk0:    BIOS drive C (66059280 X 512):
       disk0s1: FreeBSD
```

---

`fsck` didn't help. I was able to boot from USB stick and was able to enter command prompt and ran `fsck` against given filesystem. It found some errors and fix them. Finally it marked filesystem ok. I was able to mount this filesystem to some mountpoint and browse it. I saw the same `COPYRIGHT` file I saw in bootloader. Also I saw content of `/boot` directory and saw kernel files inside.

Unfortunately, once I reboot in bootloader, I have the same situation: it can't boot and it can't browse filesystem. Why? Should it still be able to do `ls`?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/533816/edit) to include: 1) the version of FreeBSD you have installed; I will assume version 12; 2) The menu or prompt you have on your screen.  Is it the `Welcome to FreeBSD` screen with numbered options 1 through 6? Or is it the `Type ? for a list of commands` followed by an `OK` prompt?

Comment: It is pfsense and your second suggestion

Comment: Sorry, that's outside my expertise.  But **please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/533816/edit)** to include more detail.  If it's a new install, I'd just redo the installation process, possibly a few times, until you get the hang of it or you find the point where you're going wrong.  Also see [this link](https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/hardware/boot-troubleshooting.html) for general boot troubleshooting guidance. It does offer suggestions for your error diagnostic.  Hopefully someone who uses pfSense can chime in.

Comment: Booting from a FreeBSD liveCD or USB stick may be helpful.  At least that way you'll have a fuller set of tools to examine the pfSense installation and the filesystems, etc. Edit your post to include the output of `lsdev` and `ls /boot`.  Directory `/boot` should contain directory `kernel` which should contain file `kernel`.  `load /boot/kernel/kernel` might work, if so then try `boot`.  You might also have an older kernel in directory `/boot/kernel.old`.  To boot that, you would `load /boot/kernel.old/kernel` and then say `boot`.

Comment: @JimL. `ls /boot` fails as any other `ls DIR` (see example above)

Comment: :(  You need to boot a FreeBSD liveCD or USB stick then.  Sounds like your filesystem is absent or damaged.

Comment: If things are bad and you have to reinstall, reinstall using ZFS filesystem if possible.  Then set a cron job to snapshot the entire pool **frequently**, like every hour or so. Then if you need to rollback it will be much easier to do, although still requiring a bootable USB stick.  You can write another cron job to delete the snapshots that are more than N days old, so the old snapshots won't hang around forever.  ZFS snapshots are a Godsend in situations like this.  Rollback, reboot, and relax! :)

Comment: Thank you, will try. The version of damaged filesystem is opposed by the fact, that I can do `ls` and can do `more COPYRIGHT`.